# Collection view in collection view items are not visible

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I have a problem where I can see like 4 items visible only from each list. I tried doing stuff like VerticalOptions Fill/FillandExpand on collection views but still can't see them all. Trying to do HeightRequest = 99999 on the outside collection view and 9999 on the inside seems to expose the items so I know they are 'there'. But this is wrong solution to the problem

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
         x:Name="AnimeListPagee"
         x:Class="OtakuApp.Pages.AnimeListPage">
<RefreshView x:Name="HomeRefreshView"
             IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}"
             Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
             RefreshColor="White"
             BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue">
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding AnimListsList}"
                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
                            SelectionMode="None"
                            x:Name="CollectionView1">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="30">
                    </Label>
                    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding entries}"
                                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                            ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
                            SelectionMode="Single"
                                            SelectedItem="{Binding BindingContext.Entry, Source={x:Reference Name=AnimeListPagee}}"
                            x:Name="CollectionView2">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding media.Title.Romaji}"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding progress}"></Label>
                                    <Frame BackgroundColor="Green">
                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <Frame BackgroundColor="Yellow" xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True"
                                                           xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding BindingContext.InfoCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=AnimeListPagee}}"></Frame>
                                            <Frame BackgroundColor="Red" xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True"
                                                           xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding BindingContext.InfoCommand2, Source={x:Reference Name=AnimeListPagee}}"></Frame>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Frame>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</RefreshView>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0Rrl.png)

Comment: can you post a screenshot that illustrates the problem?   And nesting CollectionViews is generally a pretty bad idea.  Consider using grouping instead.  What is the purpose of the ScrollView and StackLayout?  CollectionView is inherently scrollable, so a ScrollView is not needed and the StackLayout isn't doing anything useful.  That might be the cause of your problem

Comment: Some progress is made. After I've removed scrollview and stacklayout I can see all lists. But I can only see 4 items per each. And this fourth one is cut. You can see it in the middle of the screenshot. Where the watching list starts the item from previous list is cut down. The screenshot is at the bottom of the post as Stackoverflow didn't allow me to embed the image.

Comment: Can you show us the code after you remove the scrollview and stacklayout?

Comment: I edited the post with the updated code

Comment: Any ideas for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a test on my side and it seems fine. You can see if it is what you want.

**xmal:**

```
 <CollectionView x:Name="outcollection"
                 >
      <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
          <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                             ItemSpacing="0"/>
      </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
      <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                           HeightRequest="200">
              <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
              <CollectionView x:Name="insidecol" ItemsSource="{Binding peoples}">
                  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGreen">
                          <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                              <Label Text="{Binding age}"/>
                              </StackLayout>
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
              </CollectionView>
                      </StackLayout>
          </DataTemplate>
      </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
  </CollectionView>
```

**Model:**

```
 public class House
    {public string Name { set; get; }
        public string Size { set; get; }
        public List<People> peoples { set; get; }
        public House()
        {
        }
```

[image]